# A function is unbounded on a closed interval. Prove there exists a point in every neighborhood of which the function is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Let $f(x)$ be a function such that it is unbounded on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Prove there exists a point from this interval in every neighborhood of which the function is unbounded.

Below is an idea based on the nested intervals. Let there be an interval $[a, b]$. Start with splitting this interval into two equal parts:
$$
\left[a, \frac{a+b}{2}\right] \text{and}\left[\frac{a+b}{2}, b\right]
$$

Since the function is unbounded there are 3 possible scenarios here:

1. The function is unbounded on $\left[a, \frac{a+b}{2}\right]$
2. The function is unbounded on $\left[\frac{a+b}{2}, b\right]$
3. The function is unbounded on both parts of the interval.

In either case choose one of the intervals on which the function is unbounded. By repeating those steps we obtain a point which belongs to all the nested intervals. Let $c$ denote a common point.

But each interval was chosen in such a way that $f(x)$ in unbounded on that interval. We can now construct a sequence $\{x_k\}$ where $x_k \in [a,b]$ such that:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = c \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \infty
$$

Which would mean that $c$ is the point we are looking for and no matter what neighborhood of $c$ and $\epsilon > 0$ is chosen, $f(x)$ will always be unbounded for $x\in[c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon]$.

Please note this problem is given in the **"Limit of the sequences"** section and the limit of a function has not been introduced yet.

Apart from that I would like to ask for a verification or possibly other solutions just in case mine is not valid.

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: Your problem is mis-stated.  Instead of saying there is a point "in **the** neighborhood of which the function is unbounded," I believe if you read the problem carefully it says "in **every** neighborhood of which the function is unbounded." As to your proof, it is OK but to make sure you have understood matters, you should ask yourself:  If the given interval were open $(a,b)$ where would my proof break down?

Comment: @MarkFischler you are absolutely right, i've translated it incorrectly. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing item in your proof, and a point for which your professor might deduct some credit, would be "how do you know that $c$ is included in your interval (the set of points $[a,b]$)."

The point of the question is that you do know that $c$ is included in the interval because it is a limit point of a sequence of points in $[a,b]$ and a closed set includes all its limit points (by the definition of "closed set").